# Android listview produces black highlighting over text when scrolling. How to stop this?

Tags: android

```
Duplicate:
```

[Background ListView becomes black when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833057/background-listview-becomes-black-when-scrolling?lq=1)

I have a listview within which each item contains black text on a white background. When testing on a Nexus One, when scrolling down to read through the text, a black highlight appears over the text and makes it unreadable.

I am trying to figure out what is this setting so I can turn it off. I do not want anything to get highlighted when scrolling down through the list. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Background ListView becomes black when scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833057/background-listview-becomes-black-when-scrolling)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably want to set the [cacheColorHint](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:cacheColorHint) to the same color as your background.

So, when you're defining your layout, just add `android:cacheColorHint='#fff'` to your ListView:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list"
    android:cacheColorHint="#fff"
    android:background="#fff"
    ...etc />
```

Comment: @synic; what if the listview background is a gradient?

Comment: android:cacheColorHint="#000000" works for other devices but not for 4.1 and above   but  android:cacheColorHint="#fff"  works for all

Comment: @syloc did you try Paresh's suggestion below of using "@android:color/transparent"?

Answer (score 7):

This may be a trick:

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to set the backgroundcolor of your list to transparent.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and setting the `android:cacheColorHint` to transparent seems to do the trick