# Background ListView becomes black when scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I have created a specific List which exists out of the following elements to create a scrollable list with every row containing a Image on the left side and some text on the right side:

To begin with a "root" layout :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#C8C8C8"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:divider="#C8C8C8"
        android:background="#C8C8C8"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and then within the ListView I place the following "row" item :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_row"
>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10px"
        android:paddingRight="15px"
        android:paddingTop="5px"
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_image"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5px"
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:maxHeight="50px"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

As long as the screen is shown statically (as in no movement) it will be shown correctly, but when I start scrolling through the list the background of the row-item (an "icon" as can be shown in the code) will be shown correctly but the background of the "root" layout will become completely black... when the scrolling stops the background will, most of the times, get back its color...
As I test I also added a `TextView` in that root-element with the same background, this one will detain it's color when the List is scrolled...
Any idea why this is happening, and how to solve this?

Answer (score 771, accepted):

Add an attribute on the `ListView` Tag

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" // setting transparent color
```

For more details check [this blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html)

Comment: this.getListView().setCacheColorHint(0);    From layout I couldn't set the color. But I managed to do it with the above code. I have used this code in 'onCreate' of the list activity. Hope this information also helps.

Comment: `android:cacheColorHint="#0000"` also works if you're afraid of zeros.

Comment: Or also `android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"` if you're afraid of numbers :)

Comment: @android:color/transparent probably has the added bonus of having one single bit set. There is a bug where if you pass 0 on some phones transparency wont work. So the trick is to set 1 bit.

Answer (score 62):

It's very simple just use this line in your layout file :

```
android:scrollingCache="false"
```

like this:

```
<ListView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scrollingCache="false"
/>
```

Comment: It works but I don't think it is smart to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570041/scrollingcache

Comment: I had a case in which android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" did not work, but android:scrollingCache="false" did. Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

you can use like this:

```
list.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
list.requestFocus(0);
```

Answer (score 10):

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
android:divider="#C8C8C8"
android:background="#C8C8C8"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

We have plenty of options for this problem, you can set the background as transparent through programming like

```
yourlistview.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

or through xml

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 5):

In your xml where to use `Listview` set

```
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 5):

I am using images in `listView` and it turns black sometimes in samsung s4 not even scrolling. It was a stupid mistake which I have done in the adapter.I just put my *view to null* to fix this issue

```
 @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Holder holder;
            convertView = null; // convert view should be null
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new Holder();
                convertView = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.listview_draftreport_item, null);
             } 
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

There are allot of answers to this question but today I realized this question is still missing a critical piece of information.

There are *two possible solutions* for the problem, both work but each should be used in different situations.

---

**Methods**

Use `android:cacheColorHint` when your `ListView` has a *solid* color background.

```
<item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Use `android:scrollingCache` when your `ListView` has a (complex) *image* as background.

```
<item name="android:scrollingCache">false</item>
```

### Note

When your `ListView` has a solid color background both methods will work, so not only the `cacheColorHint` will work. But it's not recommended to use the `scrolingCache` method for solid color backgrounds since it turns off an optimization method used for smooth animating and scrolling the ListView.

**Note for the note:** `scrolingCache` set to false does not necessarily mean the `ListView`'s animations and scrolling will become slow.

Answer (score 2):

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me:

```
myListView.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

`android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"// setting transparent color`

or

*don't* set background of `listview`.

Answer (score 1):

Add an attribute

```js
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" //transparent color
```