# What does setScrollingCacheEnabled(); do?

Tags: android, listview, android-scroll

I initially used this method: `myListView.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);` to enhance my list view's scrolling performance. However, I feel like it is causing a small bug in my list view. And I am not sure what it actually does.

1 out of every 20 times I navigate to the activity or fragment that contains the list view. The list view is not visible, then when I touch the screen, it immediately appears.

What is the difference between `myListView.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);` and `myListView.setScrollingCacheEnabled(true);` ?

Comment: that´s like cookies here on the web. Not the same but similar function. In your case it disables the drawing cache of your listviews children (your items), so they must be "redrawn" on every scroll. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setScrollingCacheEnabled(boolean)

Comment: check this SO [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17516356/3140227)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scrollingCache?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570041/scrollingcache)