# Show more in Horizontal ScrollView in android

Tags: android, android-view, android-scrollview

I am not sure what will be the best title, but with picture, it will be clear what I want.

I have implemented Horizontal Scrollview, I have made it custom, in that only four items will be displayed and if user want to see fifth item, then he has to scroll it.
I have successfully done it.

But in android 2.3.3 it is showing **white view at the end** when there is more items, whereas in android 4.0 it is not showing. See the image below:

[image]

Look here in android 2.3, I am showing white view **which clearly telling me that, there is more buttons**, but the same result I am not getting in android 4.0 or above.
Can anybody help me how to display it.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531006/list-color-turns-black-while-scrolling

Set the cache hint color to transparent.

Comment: No @MarcelCăşvan it's not like that, i want to show that white view at the end so user can understand it, that there is more view

Comment: I see, have you considered animating the scrollview, when the user is presented with this activity? Like animate the scroll from the last item on the right, to the first

Comment: Try creating fragment tabs for same . Get reference over here ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120510/dynamically-changing-the-fragments-inside-a-fragment-tab-host/19859871#19859871. Else try using HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS); Try this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily replicate that behavior by extending the `HorizontalScrollView` widget and drawing two properly placed images/drawables:

```
public class CustomHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {

    private static final int SHADOW_WIDTH = 35;
    private GradientDrawable mDrawableLeft;
    private GradientDrawable mDrawableRight;
    private Rect mBounds = new Rect();

    public CustomHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mDrawableLeft = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT,
                new int[] { Color.GRAY, Color.TRANSPARENT });
        mDrawableRight = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT,
                new int[] { Color.GRAY, Color.TRANSPARENT });
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        // the scroll value
        final int offset = this.getScrollX();
        mBounds.setEmpty();
        mBounds.bottom = getMeasuredHeight();
        // check made to remove the shadow if we are at the left edge of the
        // screen so we don't interfere with the edge effect
        if (offset != 0) {
            // left drawable
            mBounds.left = offset;
            mBounds.right = offset + SHADOW_WIDTH;
            mDrawableLeft.setBounds(mBounds);
            mDrawableLeft.draw(canvas);
        }
        // check made to remove the shadow if we are at the right edge of the
        // screen so we don't interfere with the edge effect
        if ((offset + getMeasuredWidth()) < computeHorizontalScrollRange()) {
            // right drawable
            mBounds.left = offset + getMeasuredWidth() - SHADOW_WIDTH;
            mBounds.right = offset + getMeasuredWidth();
            mDrawableRight.setBounds(mBounds);
            mDrawableRight.draw(canvas);
        }
    }

}
```