# ListView Background Black when scrolling

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout

I am currently using fragments in my app, and in it I have a listview. When I scroll It turns black and I can't figure out how to get rid of it.

I checked out this page :
[Background ListView becomes black when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833057/background-listview-becomes-black-when-scrolling)

This didn't work... any other ideas?
(it's a listview with a picture and a text combined)

Comment: Posting your code will also help us help you :)

Comment: sorry, none of those worked it actually worked with setCacheColorHint code in java. Weird

Answer (score 7):

You can set like this

```
    <ListView 
         android:id="@+id/list01" 
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:focusable="true"    
         android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
         android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
         android:transcriptMode="normal"
         android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
         android:scrollingCache="false" 

         />
```

or can set like this

```
list.getDrawingCache(false);
list.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);  
list.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: You cant believe  android:scrollingCache="false" how important of this line to me it solve my big time problem thanks so much,,,

Answer (score 5):

or you can also set attribute

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
android:scrollingCache="false"
```

in List View.

Answer (score 2):

you can also try this

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/listtask"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:divider="@drawable/divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scrollingCache="false" >
        </ListView>
```