# Android ListView - custom row component does not redraw

Tags: android, listview, custom-component

I've got a problem with redrawing listView rows after manual scrolling top-bottom. It looks like [this](http://www.mobia.pl/temp/listView.png) (notice black stripes which should not be there):

(sorry stackOverflow was having problem with uploading image).

Each row is a custom component based on linear layout and is pretty empty right now. It is swype cell component (user can swype the cell left or right, to show left or right view).

I'm using a baseAdapter subclass where I have the following getView method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

    String infService = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(infService);
    SwypeCell v = (SwypeCell) li.inflate(R.layout.row_accounts_accounts, arg2, false);

    return v;
}
```

So my question is - how to get rid off these black stripes and redraw my custom row properly?

**EDIT:**

I think it is somehow connected with my custom component. The problem is when my custom component is a root component of the layout. The problem is solved when I put my custom component in FrameLayout.

Comment: Isn't that because of the optimization when scrolling? try android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

Comment: @MocialovBoris sorry - I added this to my listView and it did not help.

Comment: that is what I have in mind - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833057/background-listview-becomes-black-when-scrolling - maybe other options will help

Comment: @MocialovBoris thanks for suggestion, but none of the above works.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?  I have a similar issue, though my custom View is NOT the top row view element, but merely a sub-view of the row hierarchy.