# android ListView Style and colors?

Tags: android, listview

i have problem styling my listview from selector.xml items style ( background )

the colors not switched its show all the items black , i want to switch items colors between black and white , for now aim switching items colors from listview Adapter, but when i switch items colors from listview Adapter when i click on any item the item background become blue !

here is my code

```
public class Home_ForumsList_listview extends ArrayAdapter<Object>{

    private int[] colors = new int[] { 0x30ffffff, 0x30808080 };
    Context context; 
    private LayoutInflater mInflater; 
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    ArrayList ob; 
    int resource ;
    /*================================================
     *  Setup ListView
     *===============================================*/
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Home_ForumsList_listview (Context context, int resource, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") ArrayList objects) {
        super(context, resource,objects);
        this.context  = context;
        this.ob       = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        mInflater     = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    /*================================================
     *  Items Counter
     *===============================================*/
    public int getCount() {
        return ob.size();
    }
    /*================================================
     *  Item Posistion JSON
     *===============================================*/
    public JSONObject getItem(JSONObject position) {
        return position;
    }
    /*================================================
     *  Item Position
     *===============================================*/
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    /*================================================
     *  Hold Views inside Chant Bit View
     *===============================================*/
    static class ViewHolder {

        TextView  forum_title;
        TextView  forum_desc;
        TextView  forum_catagories;
        TextView  forumcode;
        Button    popup_but_id;
        RatingBar ratingsmall;
    }
    /*================================================
     *  Setup Each View raw by raw
     *===============================================*/
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        JSONObject r = (JSONObject) getItem(position);

        if(convertView == null)
        {
             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.a_home_forumslist_bit, null);
             holder = new ViewHolder();
             convertView.setTag(holder);


             holder.forum_title      = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.flist_forum_title);
             holder.forum_desc       = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.flist_forum_desc);
             holder.forum_catagories = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.flist_forum_catagories);
             holder.forumcode        = (TextView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.flist_forumcode);
             holder.ratingsmall      = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingsmall);
       }
       else
        {
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        int colorPos = position % colors.length;
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);

        try {
            holder.forum_title.setText(r.getString("forum_title"));

            if ( r.getString("forum_desc").equals(""))
            {
                holder.forum_desc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            float z = (float) r.getInt("rate");
            holder.ratingsmall.setRating(z); 
            holder.forum_desc.setText(r.getString("forum_desc"));
            holder.forumcode.setText( context.getString(R.string.forumcode) + " :   ( "+ r.getLong("forumcode") + " ) ");
            holder.forum_catagories.setText( " : " + r.getString("forum_catagories"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView; 

    } 
}
```

i googled it how to style listview , all the examples showing same colors switch from Adapter , is there any way to style listview items from selector.xml ?

sorry for my bad English ^_^ i hope you got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to alternate background colors in your list, so item 0 is white, item 1 is black, item 2 is white, etc.

First, define your colors as Android resources:

res/colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Then, use these resource identifiers as the backgrounds. Right now, you're giving it the color hex as an int, which is wrong -- it expects an int that is a resource identifier.  Like this:

```
private int[] colors = new int[] { R.color.white, R.color.black };
```

That should work.  Try it out.

To get rid of the blue highlight, you could make selectors and use those instead of just black and white:

drawable/dark_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:color="@color/gray"
    android:pressed="true" />

<item android:color="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

Then use the drawables as your backgrounds.

```
private int[] colors = new int[] { 
    R.drawable.lightSelector, 
    R.drawable.darkSelector 
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I have two thought here:

Maybe you forget to set to transparent the [cache color hint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:cacheColorHint) of the ListView, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833057/background-listview-becomes-black-when-scrolling).

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

Or maybe you need to set the [scrolling cache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:scrollingCache) on your ListView to false.

```
android:scrollingCache="false"
```

PD: it could be useful is you post your XML layout.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to alternate color of line in your listView, you can use a normal listView with an BaseAdapter of your choice.

Take a look a it :

```
package com.example.joignabilite;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Une liste de Contacts
    private List<Contact> mListP;

    // Le contexte dans lequel est présent notre adapter
    private Context mContext;

    // Un mécanisme pour gérer l'affichage graphique depuis un layout XML
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private int white = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    private int grey = 0x33000000;

    public ContactAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> aListP) {
        mContext = context;
        mListP = aListP;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mListP.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mListP.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LinearLayout layoutItem;
        // (1) : Réutilisation des layouts
        if (convertView == null) {
            // Initialisation de notre item à partir du layout XML
            // "Contact_layout.xml"
            layoutItem = (LinearLayout) mInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.item_contact, parent, false);
        } else {
            layoutItem = (LinearLayout) convertView;
        }

        // (2) : Récupération des TextView de notre layout
        TextView tv_Nom = (TextView) layoutItem
                .findViewById(R.id.repertoire_item);

        // (3) : Renseignement des valeurs
        tv_Nom.setText(mListP.get(position).nom);

        // On mémorise la position de la "Contact" dans le composant textview
        tv_Nom.setTag(position);

        /*
         * Here is the way to change color using pair and unpair line
         */
        if (position % 2 == 0)
            layoutItem.setBackgroundColor(grey);
        else
            layoutItem.setBackgroundColor(white);

        // On ajoute un listener
        tv_Nom.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Lorsque l'on clique sur le nom, on récupère la position du
                // "Contact"
                Integer position = (Integer) v.getTag();

                // On prévient les listeners qu'il y a eu un clic sur le
                // TextView "TV_Nom".
                sendListener(mListP.get(position), position);

            }

        });

        // On retourne l'item créé.
        return layoutItem;
    }

    /**
     * Interface pour écouter les évènements sur le nom d'une Contact
     */
    public interface ContactAdapterListener {
        public void onClickNom(Contact item, int position);
    }

    // Contient la liste des listeners
    private ArrayList<ContactAdapterListener> mListListener = new ArrayList<ContactAdapterListener>();

    /**
     * Pour ajouter un listener sur notre adapter
     */
    public void addListener(ContactAdapterListener aListener) {
        mListListener.add(aListener);
    }

    private void sendListener(Contact item, int position) {
        for (int i = mListListener.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            mListListener.get(i).onClickNom(item, position);
        }
    }

}
```