# Handling click event in ListView items views in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Suppose I have a ListView which items are layouts who contain three buttons. How can I know efficiently when the user has clicked the, for example, second button of the item number 5?

And also, a second question: if I have an adaptor with that getView method, how can I handle the click events in the activity class instead of the adaptor?

Cheers,

Comment: Check this may answer your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813864/android-listview-style-and-colors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually lots of ways to do this.

- You could create a Click adapter for each button that knew which Button it was attached to.
- You could put a unique tag on each button that the click handler identified and acted on.
- You could build an ArrayList linking each `Button` to a code telling the click handler what to do ...
   - As Alexander says, you can create a custom adapter for the ListView which handles the buttons. If you use this method, then you need to create the onClick handlers in

  ```
  @Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      // Create all the Views, Buttons, etc

      // Create the click handlers:
      button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
              doButtonOneClickActions(position);
          }
       });
  }

  private void doButtonOneClickActions(int rowNumber) {
      // Do the actions for Button one in row rowNumber (starts at zero)
  }
  ```

It rather depends on the rest of your code (and your preferred coding style) which solution to go for ..

Comment: Thanks Neil. That's it, I was worried about the coding style... I don't really know which is the best way. Thanks four your answer.

Comment: Please let me clarify one thing. If I have an adaptor with that getView method, how can I handle the click events in the activity class instead of the adaptor? Thanks,

Comment: @DídacPérez just create a listener in your activity and pass it to your adapter after initialization, but before assign it to listview.

Answer (score 2):

For this purposes you should better create custom adapter for a `ListView`. Then override `getView`:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
//here you define your button's click events.
//use position parameter to get actual position of current row layout in 
// the list
 }
```

Comment: Thanks four your answer. I actually have implemented a custom adapter and the getView method, but I do need to know how to handle events over the items of the list view in a efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

You should create custom adapter and override `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method and there reference your buttons and set them `onClickListeners`. There you have `position` of list row so you have everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

how wonderful that you put three buttons in the list item just like I am doing now! I too am looking for a coding style (not necessarily a solution). Anyway, I would aim at:

1. Performance
2. Re-usability
3. Loosely coupled (yet highly cohesive)

I will delegate the click handlers to an external instance which shall be defined and wired to the adapter using:

```java
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    View.OnClickListener listener = null;

    public View getView(...) {
        buttonA.setOnClickListener(listener);
        buttonB.setOnClickListener(listener);
        buttonC.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }
    public void setItemClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

It's the listener's job to identify which button has been click. More issues must be address, for example, passing data from MyListAdapter to the listener, and streamlining the listener code as a part of the application logics.