# Problems When Changing Visibility and Background of a View

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-drawable

I have a `LinearLayout` in which a `TextView`'s visibility and background (`GradientDrawable`) changes according to a function `myFunction()`:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    (...Some views...)


    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentPercentage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="XX.X%"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The `currentPercentage` `TextView` has `GONE` visibility by default and, according to some events in the fragment that contains it, may have it changed to Visible (or back to `GONE`) and its background to a different `GradientDrawable` like so:

```
myFunction(...){

    TextView currentPercentage= (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.currentPercentage);

    if(condition ... ) {

        Color color = // Color based on the condition...
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.TL_BR,
            new int[] {color,color});
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int dp = Math.round(10f / (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
        gd.setCornerRadius(dp);
        currentChartPercentage.setBackground(gd);

    } else if( otherCondition...)
    {
        // ... similar stuff ...
    } else {
        // Hide the currentPercentage TextView
        currentPercentage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

This works fine as the `TextView`'s background and visibility change smoothly whenever `myFunction()` is called and the other elements in the `LinearLayout` move (with animation) to make room for the `TextView`.

My issue is that whenever the visibility goes from GONE to VISIBLE, the View fades in nicely (as expected because of `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`) but right in the end shows up with an annoying black background where the `GradientDrawable` round corners are (see image).

[image: Annoying Black Background]

Right after that, if I touch something else or drag the fragment (it's inside a `ViewPager`), the black background disappears. If `myFunction()` is called again, with the View already VISIBLE, then the background color changes as desired with no black background.

Also, if I disable the animation, I don't get the black background too. Thus, the problem seems to be related to the visibility going from GONE to VISIBLE with an animation.

[image: Round Corners OK]

This behavior is obtained on an emulator with Android 4.3 and I haven't tested it on my real device yet.

Does anybody have a clue on why this may be happening?

**EDIT:**

Just tested this on a real device with ICS without any issue.

**EDIT 2:**

I once had a problem with an undesirable background showing up in a ListView similar to [Background ListView becomes black when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833057/background-listview-becomes-black-when-scrolling?rq=1) but in this case, setting a `cacheColorHint` does nothing.

Comment: what is the default background of the textview?  have you tried setting it to transparent?

Comment: Yup, I've tried both Transparent and @null already. Unfortunately, didn't do a thing.