# Disable ListView Selection - Xamarin Android

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Today I discovered a strange effect in my Xamarin Android app. The main screen of an app normally looks like this:

[image: normal]

As you can see, the main list items are transparent. But when I'm trying to scroll this small list of three items the following ugly effect appears:

[image: bug]

List selector for list is set to @color/transparent. List item background is @color/transparent, so I have NO effects when the list item is clicked/focused/enabled/disabled. I also set list android:choiceMode to none.
Even with small scrolling gesture all three items are ALWAYS highlighted like this.
Note: this bug only occurs when I set target framework to less than API 14 (e.g. for android 3.x support). In android 4.x everything is okay!
Please help me to get rid of this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Background ListView becomes black when scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833057/background-listview-becomes-black-when-scrolling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the culprit, you can either set:

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

or:

```
android:scrollingCache="false"
```

for you ListView!